How to fix model after boolean?

I've added a boolean to my circle and these extra lines appeared.. Face Orientation is OK, no problems with vertices Merge.

I guess, my problem with bevel but no ideas how to fix it, could somebody help me, please?)


Mmm.. well, I fixed my problem by adding loop cut, but don't understand why it's working?
Here's my model: 

I would try adding a bevel modifier after the booleans, based on angles. With harden normals enabled. And/or a weighted normal modifier.

Hi , please could you share your .blend file?
so people that want to answer no need to re-create your model,
since your issue it's quite specific.

@CheatPekalongan, my bad, I should have uploaded it before, now it's below of my question (I hope I've uploaded it correctly cause doing it first time)

In your case, the simplest way is to bump up your sub-d modifier to level 2. This creates an edge close enough to where the boolean ends.

You can get the same result by adding some edge loops in the mesh, which you really should do anyway, it helps your sub-d mod give a more cylindrical shape along the length of your "barrel" shape

Then you can add a few more to help enforce the flow from the sub-d mod. This should reduce the "lines" to be basically invisible.


Thanks, got it now!)
